# Add 1 to each element using .map

Tags: javascript, function, dictionary

I have an array created and I would like to know how to use the .map function to add 1 to each element of the array

```js
function range(n){
  let arr= [...Array(n).keys()];
}
```

Comment: `arr.map(el => el + 1)`

Comment: `let arr= [...Array(n).keys()].map(n=>n+1)` ?

Comment: @Bravo—how does that "*add 1 to each element of the array*"? Assuming *n* is a positive integer, it just returns a list of values from 0 to n-1, it doesn't access or increment the values at all.

Comment: @RobG - the original code produces an array `[0, 1, 2, ..., n-1]` ... how do you add 1 to each element in such an array ... `.map(n => n+1)` ... it answers he question, does it not?

Comment: @Bravo—I assumed the OP's code is on the wrong track using *keys* as it doesn't access the values. I guess if the requirement is to produce an array with values from 1 to n, then it might be OK. But `[...Array(n+1).keys()].slice(-n)` does the job a little more succinctly (provided *n* is first tested to be a positive integer greater than 0). ;-)

Comment: @RobG - yeah, there's always more than one way to skin a cat in javascript

Answer (score 0):

JS arrays are zero index based, so keys will return values starting from zero, you need to manually add the `1` so either add `.map(i=> i+1)` after arr, or you can simply use `Array.from` instead,

```js
function range(n) {
  let arr = Array.from({
    length: n
  }, (_, i) => i + 1)
  return arr
}

console.log(range(9))
```